# How to config minttyrc for zoom

Tags: cygwin, mintty

How to do this automatically?

I have to press Ctrl++ multiple times every time I open mintty to zoom the screen.

Thanks and welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I have to press Ctrl++ multiple times every time I open `mintty` to zoom the screen.

Instead of doing this, set the correct font size for `mintty` that matches your requirements:

1. Right click on the mintty title bar.
2. Select "Options".
3. Select "Text".
4. Press "Select".
5. Choose your font size.
6. Press "OK", then press "Save".

   [image]